# My Alexa Skill works in Europe but not in the USA

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a skill for Alexa using NodeJS running in AWS Lambda functions. The skill works great in my location (Europe) but my client from USA gets errors. The NodeJS uses SessionAttributes and that is what I believe it fails, since the intents that don't have sessionAttributes they are triggered in USA but the rest of intents fail.

I thought it could be because my AWS Lambda function is in Europe, so I created/duplicated one in USA through my AWS account portal and configured it in alexa developer console as follows:
[image]

Unfortunately keeps failing. Also, I changed the USA lambda function to default Region(1) but same fails in usa and works great for me.

We tested the skill with both echo device and through the Alexa developer console Test Page.

I would really appreciate some advice if someone knows a workaround or had this issue before. The NodeJS code of the lambda functions is confidential and works great so surely it is something from the regions.

Comment: A backend in Europe should work fine for a user of you skill in USA but with more lag, that's all. If it fails the problem is in the implementation. You say you use session attributes. Are you expecting them to survive sessions maybe? The only thing I can think of is that you expect that and in Europe you get the same lambda instance while in north america your lamda instance gets replaced more quickly. Try persistent attributes instead. Any backend code that you can show?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are using the correct regions. Here is the list of the regions you can use ASK trigger with.

US East (N. Virginia)
EU (Ireland)
US West (Oregon)
Asia Pacific(Tokyo)

you cannot use other regions to trigger ask.

Also, I think there is a limit to the size of data you can send in session attributes. It should not exceed 24kb.